# WPF Label content shows DependencyProperty.UnsetValue in design mode

Tags: c#, wpf, label, wpf-controls

I have an WPF label and I have bound some data into a string using StringFormat from xaml:

```
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource MyLblResource}">
    <Label.Content>
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}({0}) {1}">
                    <Binding Path="MyDataModel.Id" />
                    <Binding Path="MyDataModel.Desc" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </Label.Content>
</Label>
```

Above code works fine, no problems but in design time, in xaml view, in the TextBlock content it is shown:

```
{{DependecyProperty.UnsetValue}} {{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}}
```

Why is this being shown instead of being shown as empty? Is there any way to show this as empty?

Comment: you can use a converter instead of stringformat, and compare with unset value in its body

Comment: feel free to mark my answer mate

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
 public class StringFormatConverter : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public string StringFormat { get; set; } = @"({0}) {1}";

        public string PlaceHolder { get; set; } = "Empty";

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => this;

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return string.Format(StringFormat, GetValues(values));
        }

        private IEnumerable<string> GetValues(object[] values)
        {
            foreach (var value in values)
                yield return value == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue || value == null ? PlaceHolder : value.ToString();
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return new[] { Binding.DoNothing, Binding.DoNothing };
        }
    }
```

Use it like this:

```
 <MultiBinding Converter="{converter:StringFormatConverter PlaceHolder=MyPlaceHolderText}">
   <Binding Path="MyDataModel.Id" />
   <Binding Path="MyDataModel.Desc" />
</MultiBinding>
```

Please be aware that you can only set `static` values in `StringFormat` and `PlaceHolder` - because they are no `DependencyProperty`.

Comment: I am using NET 3.5 so assigning a value for the properties is not working. Also lambda used in ProvideValue method is not working. Coluld you adapt it to net 3.5?

Comment: replace `=> this;` with `{ return this; }`. Also please check my comment "Please be aware that you can only set static values in StringFormat and PlaceHolder - because they are no DependencyProperty."

Comment: Tomorrow I will check and if it is working and I will accept your answer as the correct one. Thx.

Comment: Working - pls check !